# The game crashes after the build for android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with the game crashing after the build. If I run the game in Unity, then everything works. And when I build it on android, when I start the first training scenes work fine, but when I reach the main stage, the game crashes. There is a error in Unity:

```
Google.JarResolver.ResolutionException: Cannot find candidate artifact for com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4+
```

Maybe that's the problem. If that's not the problem, how do you know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

So this looks like plugin resolve problem. But more information wouldnt be bad and you should learn how to see your device logs on Android. Here is how:

You should check the logs of your mobile device in the moment of the crash. You can do it by using "adb logcat".

- First you should download [SDK Platform Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html).
- Then, enable USB debugging on your phone.
- Connect your phone to your PC and give the permission it needs. It will ask you when you first connect it.
- Open command line on your computer, go to your SDK Platform Tools folder, copy the directory and paste it after writing "cd " to your command line

Now you can use adb to figure out your Android crashes. To filter the ADB you can use

```
adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG
```

This way you will only see Unity related logs from your device.